# Silverlight drop shadow appears at the wrong angle

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, shadow

I am using `DropShadowEffect` to display a shadow in Silverlight.  I set the angle to 270 which works in WPF and, upon checking the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.direction%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), should give a vertically downwards shadow.

In reality what I actually get is a shadow at around the 225 degree mark.

Why is this happeniing? If I set the shadow to 90 degrees I get a vertically upwards shadow as you would expect, in fact setting the shadow to -90 gives the desired effect.

```
<Border.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="1" Direction="270" Opacity="0.5"/>
</Border.Effect>
```

Comment: I just tested with `Direction` set to 275 in an SL proj got the desired result just fine?

Comment: Did you test with 270? It seems that the other directions ive chosen work correctly (although i didnt test something so close) but 270 doesnt work

Comment: 270 seemed to display it just a little bit to the left more than I would consider centered below the object. Except it wasn't an overly noticeable offset.

Comment: It is noticeable under circumstances and regardless of this is not correct... very interesting why this happens!